# Generate realistic sequence of numbers in SQL based on a random floor/ceiling

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, random

I have a table that holds the `PRICEDATE` and `UNITPRICE`

I am creating a `CTE` to create a row for each day between the latest `PRICEDATE` and today so that we can populate the table with demo data (this is a demo system)

I'd like to take the latest `UNITPRICE` as a starting point and then generate 'realistic' prices by making the next row's `UNITPRICE` a random number whereby it is the previous `UNITPRICE` up or down by a certain amount

eg: the latest `UNITPRICE` is 1.45678, so I'd like to generate a random number for the next row by taking the previous value (1.45678) and creating a new number that can be anywhere between -0.05 and 0.05 from the last one (1.40678 and 1.50678). Each subsequent row is a random deviation (-0.05 to 0.05) of the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with p as (
      select @PriceDate as pricedate, @UnitPrice as price
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, pricedate),
             price + 0.05 - rand(checksum(newid()))*0.1
      from p
      where dateadd(day, 1, pricedate) <= @EndDate
     )
select *
from p
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I'm not sure exactly how you want to provide the initial numbers, so I put placeholders in for variables that have the initial values.

EDIT: amended 0.5 to 0.05 to reflect my question. Mike.

Comment: You might need to set the `MAXRECURSION` option if this recursive CTE is going to generate more than 100 values.

Comment: Excellent point Ed, thanks. I did have `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` at the end of my CTE